# Get "PASS" or "FAILED" with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My formula displays "PASS" or "FAILED" based on multiple criteria. The problem is that it displays "PASS" when the cells `G2:I2` are blank. The desired behavior is that it should display "FAILED" when one or more of the cells `G2:I2` are blank. How do I make that happen?

`=IF(and(G2<0.28, H2<0.28, I2<0.28, G2>-0.28, H2>-0.28, I2>-0.28,ISBLANK(M2)),"PASS","FAILED")`

Comment: Please share what is the input and the expected output

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results, row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  isblank(G2), "FAILED", 
  isblank(H2), "FAILED", 
  isblank(I2), "FAILED", 
  not(isblank(M2)), "FAILED", 
  not(isbetween(G2, -0.28, 0.28)), "FAILED", 
  not(isbetween(H2, -0.28, 0.28)), "FAILED", 
  not(isbetween(I2, -0.28, 0.28)), "FAILED", 
  true, "PASS" 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTA()` to check how many values are there inside a given `RANGE`, and use `ArrayFormula()` to apply calculation to every cell of a range, instead of checking the cell one by one.

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(RANGE,
 IF(
  AND(
   COUNTA(RANGE)=3,
   RANGE>-0.28,
   RANGE<0.28,
   ISBLANK($M$2)
  ),
  "PASS",
  "FAILED"
 )
)($G$2:$I$2))
```

Answer (score 0):

null (empty) value is considered as 0 so try:

```
=IF(AND(G2<>"",   H2<>"",   I2<>"", 
        G2<0.28,  H2<0.28,  I2<0.28, 
        G2>-0.28, H2>-0.28, I2>-0.28, ISBLANK(M2)), "PASS", "FAILED")
```